# Nextcloudcmd SSL issues

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, nextcloud

I'm encountering issues with nextcloudcmd on my Linux instance, more precisely SSL errors

```
/usr/bin/nextcloudcmd --trust -u {USER_NAME} -p {PASSWORD} {SOURCE_DIR} {URL}
```

output:

```
08-28 17:17:14:180 [ info nextcloud.sync.accessmanager ]:       2 "" "{URL}" has X-Request-ID "e34c161a-dcb4-4ff5-a537-769f6cb614d5"
08-28 17:17:14:181 [ info nextcloud.sync.networkjob ]:  OCC::JsonApiJob created for "{URL}" + "ocs/v1.php/cloud/capabilities" ""
08-28 17:17:14:228 [ info nextcloud.sync.account ]:     "SSL-Errors happened for url  \"https://{URL}/ocs/v1.php/cloud/capabilities?format=json\" \tError in  QSslCertificate(\"3\", \"36:2c:44:d4:b2:db:19:84:53:74:af:20\", \"NTf2uzPSJ1u7frYX8PRDeQ==\", \"AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4\", \"*.{URL}\", QMap((1, \"{URL}\")(1, \"*.{URL}\")), QDateTime(2023-08-03 07:38:22.000 UTC Qt::UTC), QDateTime(2024-09-03 07:38:21.000 UTC Qt::UTC)) : \"The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found\" ( \"The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found\" ) \n \tError in  QSslCertificate(\"3\", \"36:2c:44:d4:b2:db:19:84:53:74:af:20\", \"NTf2uzPSJ1u7frYX8PRDeQ==\", \"AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G4\", \"*.{URL}\", QMap((1, \"{URL}\")(1, \"*.{URL}\")), QDateTime(2023-08-03 07:38:22.000 UTC Qt::UTC), QDateTime(2024-09-03 07:38:21.000 UTC Qt::UTC)) : \"No certificates could be verified\" ( \"No certificates could be verified\" ) \n " Certs are known and trusted! This is not an actual error.
```

The {URL} i'm trying to connect to is not hosted by myself, so I don't have access to configuration files or anything like that

The output is the same, regardless of the

```
--trust
```

option

Am I doing something wrong, or is this something I have no control over, and should I conact the {URL} host?

I noticed that the issue also happens on Windows, I just recieved a pop-up and after clicking "confirm" once it started to work again like it used to

It worked perfectly fine up untill yesterday (2023-08-27) around noon, thats when this issue
arose

Kind regards